# Bundle my Python code along with all dependencies

Tags: python, deployment, bundle, package

In order to reduce my application deployment time, I want to create a zip of my Python program with all packages.

My next step would be to zip packages from a private PyPi source, so pyinstaller will not be good enough.

Is there any way to bundle these packages together before packing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command: pip install package_name --target .

This will download the package into your local directory but will not install its' dependencies